# Powermock calling actual private method instead of mocking

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, powermock

I want to mock the private method "downloadFromNexus" but instead of mocking, actual method gets called while trying to mock here `PowerMockito.doReturn("").when(spy, "downloadFromNexus", "", "");`

```
@Component(value = "DownloadXFile")
@Order(1)
@Slf4j
public class DownloadXFile implements DownloadJarFiles {

    @Value("${path}")
    private String path;

    @Override
    public void download() throws IOException {
        ....
        downloadFromNexus(path, outputFilePath);
        log.info("jar {} downloaded", jar);
    }

    private void downloadFromNexus(final String url, final String outputFilePath) throws IOException {
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(
                new URL(url),
                new File(outputFilePath),
                2000,
                2000);
    }
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(DownloadXFile.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = DownloadXFile.class)
class DownloadXTest {

    @Autowired
    DownloadXFile downloadXFile;


    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        final DownloadXFilespy = PowerMockito.spy(downloadXFile);
        PowerMockito.doReturn("").when(spy, "downloadFromNexus", "", "");
        downloadXFile.download();
        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(spy, Mockito.times(1)).invoke("downloadFromNexus");
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.42-beta</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You called `downloadXFile.download();` on original object instead of the spy.